# I can't write to input in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-textinput, react-flatlist

I am trying to learn React Native. I have an example but there is a problem in the FlatList. I have a TextInput in the footer component. There is no error but when I try to write to the input field the keybord cant stay. It just appears and then dissapears. How can I fix this problem?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
    Text,
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Image,
    Button,
    Alert,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
    FlatList,
} from "react-native";

function MyHeader() {
    return (
        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 40, marginVertical: 60 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 24, marginBottom: 30 }}>
                Hello React Native
            </Text>
            <ActivityIndicator
                size="large"
                color="#c1262c"
                style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

function MyFooter() {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const inputText = (text) => {
        setText(text);
    };

    const alertMessage = text;
    return (
        <View>
            <View
                    style={{
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: "black",
                    padding: 20,
                    marginBottom: 30,
                }}
            >
                <Text>Hello again!</Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: "black",
                    padding: 20,
                    marginBottom: 30,
                }}
                value={text}
                onChangeText={inputText}
            />
            <Button
                onPress={() => Alert.alert(alertMessage)}
                title="Learn More"
                color="#c1262"
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    const randomNum = useRef(Math.random()).current;

    return (
        <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={MyHeader}
            data={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert(`You pressed image #${item + 1}`)}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={{
                                uri: `https://picsum.photos/500/300?random=${randomNum + item}`,
                            }}
                            style={{ width: "100%", height: 160, marginBottom: 30 }}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item)}
            ListFooterComponent={MyFooter}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue using an iPhoneX Simulator running iOS 12.4. I copied your code above into an app and the keyboard remained open for me. Might need a bit more information about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

just change or remove onChangeText={inputText}

Comment: I tried now, unfortunately it didn't work. Also I try to set alert message with inputText and it was working when I try with ScrollView.